# Automatizar input de enter na command line durante a execução de um bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, automatização, setup

Eu criei um script em bash para automatizar a instalação e configuração do meu ambiente necessário pra rodar meu projeto, porém algumas das tarefas solicitam que as ações sejam confirmadas dando enter, gostaria de saber como posso automatizar este input (de um ENTER) no script para que ele possa ser executado por completo sem nenhuma interação humana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer:

```
echo | [o seu comando que necessita de input]
```

Um exemplo. Imagine que tem um directorio chamado `OMeuDirectorio` e deseja apaga-lo com `rm OMeuDirectorio -ri` (note o `i` para que o `rm` seja executado interactivamente).

Para fazê-lo de forma automatizada, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
echo 'y' | rm OMeuDirectorio -ri
```

O carácter `y` e passado para o *stdinput* e consumido pela função da próxima vez que for necessário uma interacção do utilizador.

No seu caso, como um dos seus comandos vai necessitar de um `Enter`, basta invocar o comando como disse a cima (passar o `echo` por pipeline para o seu comando).

(Note que o `echo` produz uma nova linha (um `Enter`) por defeito).

Comment: Não entendi, no caso o meu comando que está solicitando o input, deve preceder o echo |  seria isto?

Comment: Compreendido, aceitei a resposta, obrigado @Omni